# if statement negation python 2.7.8

Tags: python, if-statement, negation

Hi I'm fairly new to coding and I'm stuck on negation and how to properly implement it. 
 I've been going through a textbook teaching myself and I'm stuck 
"Write an if statement that negates n, if and only if it is less than 0"

I've tried and failed miserably, any tips or help would be appreciated.

```
if -n > 0:
n = 1
```

Comment: Be aware that indentation is crucial for python to work. So `n = 1` must be indented at least one space.

Comment: While `if -n > 0:` does work, why did you write it that way instead of the more straightforward `if n < 0:`?

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
if n < 0:
    n = -n
```

The `if` statement checks if `n` is less than zero. If this is the case, it assigns `-n` to `n`, effectively negating `n`.

If you replace `n` with an actual number, you'll see how it works:

```
n = -10
if n < 0:   # test if -10 is less than 0, yes this is the case
    n = -n  # n now becomes -(-10), so 10

n = 10
if n < 0:   # test if 10 is less than 0, no this is not the case
    n = -n  # this is not executed, n is still 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Negation requires assigning a value to n. "If and only if" requires an if statement.

```
if n < 0:
    n = -n
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if n < 0:
  n = n * -1

print n
```

I think this is as simple as it gets for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
n = abs(n)
```

Is the same.. if it's negative, it will be positive, and if it's positive.. it will be still positive

Comment: Technically, you're right, but since this seems to be a homework question, this is not the right answer.

Comment: Maybe the teacher think that he thinks differently than the others :P

Answer (score 1):

Usually Python programmers use the **`not`** keyword for negating conditionals:

```
if not -n > 0:
    n = 1
```

(Although, that example is a bit convoluted and will probably be easier to maintain as `if n < 0: ...`).

One nice thing about Python conditional expressions is that the use of `not` can be done in a way that reads naturally to English speakers.  For example I can say `if 'a' not in 'someword': ...` and it's the same (semantically) as if I coded that as `if not 'a' in 'someword': ...` This is particularly handy when testing object identity using `is` ... for example: `if not a is b: ...` (test if 'a' and 'b' are references to the same object) can also be written `if a is not b: ...`

Comment: Incidentally one of the things which I most appreciate about Python is that good Python code is more often readable as natural English than any other programming language I've used.  Of course there's lots of "myinstance.do_something(someother_thing)" ... which isn't exactly smooth flowing narrative.  But it's still nicer to read than most other programming code.